# Warming - Arquivo Fonte não compilado

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Toda vez que crio um código da este erro, sendo que consigo compilar normalmente, mas quando tento executar ocorre isso, como devo proceder?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Vai na pasta onde VC salvou e veja se tem o .EXE do seu programa.Se sim tenta rodar ele.Você pode tentar fazer seus programas no codeblocks e também tem uma solução na nuvem que se chama cloud9.io

Answer (score 0):

Tenho duas dicas para você:

- Não coloque espaço no nome da pasta e do programa. Use `ProgramasFaculdade/QuantidadeAzulejos.cpp`
- Coloque `return 0;` no final do seu código.